# Is there a better way to re.search a string many times?

Tags: python, perl, search

Perl Code

```
while(<file_handle>){
  if(/if\s+\((\w+)\)/){
    $op = 0x10;
    print "This is if state!", $1；
  }elsif(/(\d+)/){
    push(@number, $1);
    print "This is pure number", $1；
  }
}
```

This is very pretty! But in python:

```
for line in lines:
  result = re.search('/if\s+\((\w+)\)/', line)
  if result:
    op = int("10", 16);
    print "This is if state!" + result.group(1)
  else:
    result = re.search('/(\d+)/', line)
    if result:
      number.append($1)
      print result.group(1)
```

Is there a better way to write this part in python?
I know in this case we can use [\w|\d]+ in 1 if statement. But sometimes we have to use several different if statement.

Add some input file example:

```
move r1, r2;
if (en){
  r3 = r5 * r6;
}
r10 = 0;
for (r7 = 0; r7<10; r7++){
  r10 = r10 + r7;
}
```

Comment: your goal is to print out characters or digits? Can you give an example of what an input looks like, and expected resulting output?

Comment: I add an example. Do you mean no matter what's the text is and the search pattern is, there is a way to use 1 if statement?

Comment: That `elsif` clause will never be entered because `\w` includes all of `\d`.

Comment: Thanks ! This is just an example not actually what I write in my code. Is there any beautiful way to describe the same logic with Python.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it's not worth the bother for just two regex patterns. Here's a paradigm that works for enough patterns to make the effort worth the while.

Put the regexes in a list. For each string to be examined spin through the list comparing each string against each regex in the list.

```
>>> import re
>>> patterns = [r'(dog)', r'(lion)', r'(rat)', r'(cat)']
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> lines = StringIO('''\
... dog orangutan bear cat
... lion rat cat
... mouse rat beast
... sealion cow horse''')
>>> for line in  lines:
...     print (line)
...     for pattern in patterns:
...         m = re.search(pattern, line)
...         if m:
...             print(m.groups(0))
... 
dog orangutan bear cat

('dog',)
('cat',)
lion rat cat

('lion',)
('rat',)
('cat',)
mouse rat beast

('rat',)
sealion cow horse
('lion',)
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I do if I need do different instructors in different branches?

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I update the question. I want to do the exactly same thing like Perl. If loop is used we have to use "next" to exit the loop once the word is  matched.

Comment: Rather than making a significant change to an existing question you should post a new question. If this answer provided a solution to your *original* question then it should be marked accepted.

Comment: I wanner to know a equivalent solution not a alternative solution. What I edit just make the problem more clear.